# MS CRM 3.0 , CRMWEBSERVICE,

Tags: c#, web-services, dynamics-crm-3

We have a ms crm 3 instance installed and running on a VM, we have created a separate project and are creating a custom web service.

We also added web references to the crm webservice as well as the metadata service and it connected fine. However when we try and use the `CRMService.[entity]` it is not providing us with any of the entities for example account or case or anything.

Do you have any ideas on what the possible resolution to this could be?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was CRM seems to have multiple web services with the same name. so if u enter http://[server]/[website]/crmservices it finds it fine but doesnt contain any of the entities however if you have http://[server]/crmservices it works fine